# Autenticação usando php e Azure webapp services

Tags: php, web-service, microsoft-azure, firebase

Existe algo como Firebase - com autenticação prontas para AZURE cloud?

Como eu faço a questão do `php`? Você podem me ajudar com um exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Veja aqui [como configurar seu aplicativo de Serviço de Aplicativo para usar o logon do Active Directory do Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]